# Subtracting timespan from 24 hours

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I'm trying to subtract my potentially negative timespan values from 24 hours to change them into positive values.

As an example case:

I want to find how much time is there till 8:00 AM.

If it's 16:00 PM now, timespan gives me -8 ish value so I want to substract it from 24 to get 16.

I'm trying this but it's giving me this error

> The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar
>   System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

What I tried ;

```
string startTime = String.Format("{0:t}", "8:00");

TimeSpan timeLeft = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime).Subtract(DateTime.Now);

if (timeLeft.TotalMinutes < 0 )
{
    timeLeft = Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("{0:H}","24:00")).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(timeLeft.Negate())) ;
}
```

How can I achieve subtracting my potentially negative timespans from 24 hours?

Comment: No Joda time in C#? 

Comment: @RavindranathAkila > there are some projects like http://nodatime.org/. But honestly, DateTime API is quite efficient, the code in first post is a real mess due to OP lack of understanding of C# (Ege, please don't see any offense here), it doesn't represent a good usage of DateTime tooling.

Comment: @Ege - What *precisely* do you mean by "8:00 AM"?  Do you mean 8:00 AM in the local time zone on the computer where the code is running?  Or perhaps somewhere else on the Earth or in Universal Time?  What if I gave you an input like "2:30 AM" but it happened to run on the day of a spring-forward DST transition where the clocks shift from 2:00 to 3:00?  Also, what do you mean by "how much time"? Do you mean *duration of time elapsed*? Or do you mean difference in wall time?  Again, on a DST transition, you might have more or less. [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) will help address all of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing `TimeSpan` and `DateTime`. I guess there is an easier way:

```
var eightOClock = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
var now = DateTime.Now;

var till8again = now.TimeOfDay > eightOClock 
                 ? TimeSpan.FromHours(32) - now.TimeOfDay 
                 : eightOClock - now.TimeOfDay;
```

So if `TimeOfDay` is less than eight hours (it's before 8am), we take the difference to 8am. If it's greater than 8am, we take the difference to 32hours, which is 8am tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

A DateTime is an absolute date, happening at a certain day, month, year... It must not be used to represent a specific hour. 
So your attempt to convert "8:00", or "24:00" in a DateTime will forcibly fail.

For this you must use TimeSpan (or eventually an integer if you always work with hours).

You can use for example

```
if(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > TimeSpan.FromHours(8))
```

To see if it's more or less than 8:00.

TimeOfDay will return you the amount of time elapsed for today since midnight.

DateTime has also a lot of useful methods to Add or Substract time, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx for details

Answer (score 1):

Use `TimeSpan`, and if the `startDate` is less the `Now`, add a day to it and then make the comparison.

```
TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(8,0,0);
TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

startTime = startTime < now ? startTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)) : startTime;
TimeSpan diff = startTime - now;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another point: the error is coming from the fact that 24:00 doesn't represent 12:00 midnight. 0:00 represents midnight, and that will be a valid DateTime.